# How can I have an object wrap around screen?

Tags: java, coordinate-transformation

I'm working on a program that takes a ship object and it moves it. The trouble I am having is that if it goes past a side, then it is supposed to wrap back around on the other side.

Any help would be great :)

Here is my ship Class: The move method is what I need help with. The code I have doesnt work :/

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class Ship {

private BufferedImage _image;
private static final int WIDTH = 50;

private Point location;
private Vector speed = new Vector();
private double facing;

/**
 * Generate ship at the given starting location and currently stopped
 * 
 * @param starting
 *            location to copy for this ship
 */
public Ship(Point starting) {
    try {
        // Use the RunConfigurations >> Arguments > Working Directory tab so
        // that this works. Don't just place the nave.png file in the bin
        // directory!
        _image = ImageIO.read(new File("nave.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot find ship _image: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    location = starting.clone();
    facing = Math.PI;
}

public void accelerate(double force) {
    // TODO change the speed (velocity, really) by force in the direction
    // the ship is facing.
    // add a vector of appropriate magnitude by the facing direction

    Vector acc = new Vector(facing);

    acc = acc.scale(force);

    speed = speed.add(acc);

}

public void rotate(double angle) {
    // TODO change the direction the ship is facing. Can accept any angle
    // as a parameter but should store it as in [0,2*pi)

    while (angle <= 0.0f) {
        angle += (Math.PI * 2);
    }
    while (angle >= Math.PI) {
        angle -= (Math.PI * 2);
    }

    facing += angle;

}

public void move(Dimension bounds) {
    // TODO Move the ship its speed. The ship should wrap around
    // within its box. (Hint: move the ship by the size of the
    // bounding area to wrap it around; you may need to do this
    // more than once if the ship is moving fast enough.)

    location = speed.move(location);

    while (location.getX() > bounds.width) {
        Vector v = new Vector(location.getX() - WIDTH);
        location = v.move(location);
    }

    while (location.getX() < -WIDTH) {
        Vector v = new Vector(location.getX() + WIDTH);
        location = v.move(location);
    }

    while (location.getY() > bounds.height) {
        Vector v = new Vector(location.getY() - WIDTH);
        location = v.move(location);
    }

    while (location.getY() < -WIDTH) {
        Vector v = new Vector(location.y() + WIDTH);
        location = v.move(location);
    }

}

public void draw(Graphics g2d) {
    double locationX = _image.getWidth() / 2;
    double locationY = _image.getHeight() / 2;
    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(facing,
            locationX, locationY);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx,
            AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations
    // Code for rotating adapted from StackOverflow.
    g2d.drawImage(op.filter(_image, null), location.getX(),
            location.getY(), null);
}
```

And here is my vector class: All this code works :)

```
public class Vector {

private final double _dx, _dy;

public Vector() {
    _dy = 0.0;
    _dx = 0.0;
}

public Vector(double x, double y) {
    _dx = x;
    _dy = y;
}

public Vector(Point a, Point b) {
    _dx = b.x() - a.x();
    _dy = b.y() - a.y();
}

public Vector(double angle) {
    _dx = Math.cos(angle);
    _dy = Math.sin(angle);
}

public double dx() {
    return _dx;
}

public double dy() {
    return _dy;
}

public Point move(Point b) {

    double x = b.x();
    double y = b.y();
    x += _dx;
    y += _dy;

    return new Point(x, y);

}

public Vector add(Vector a) {
    double x = (a._dx + _dx);
    double y = (a._dy + _dy);

    return new Vector(x, y);
}

public Vector scale(double s) {
    double x = _dx * s;
    double y = _dy * s;

    return new Vector(x, y);
}

public double magnitude() {
    double x = Math.pow(_dx, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(_dy, 2);

    return Math.sqrt(x + y);
}

public Vector normalize() {
    double x = _dx / magnitude();
    double y = _dy / magnitude();
    return new Vector(x, y);
}

public Vector rotate(double rads) {
    double theta = angle();
    theta += rads;
    return new Vector(theta);
}

public double angle() {
    double alpha = Math.acos(dx() / magnitude());
    if (dy() < 0)
        alpha = Math.PI - alpha;
    return alpha;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String vector = "[" + _dx + "," + _dy + "]";
    return vector;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Vector) {
        Vector vector = (Vector) obj;
        if ((Math.abs(_dx - vector._dx) <= (1 / 10000000000f))
                && (Math.abs(_dy - vector._dy) <= (1 / 10000000000f)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else
        return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) Math.round((angle() * 180) / Math.PI);
}
```

}

Comment: A few things.  You've posted a lot of code, most of which is likely unrelated to your problem.  Also, don't use `Vector` as that is deprecated.  Try `ArrayList<T>` instead.  Finally, consider modulus math when you need something to loop (or start over) when it overflows...

Comment: Doh, I see this is a custom Vector.  Ignore that part of my last comment.

Comment: Could you provide any code for the modulus math? the method above move does essentially the same thing with the while loops

Comment: @Programatic I've provided a concrete implementation using modulo. Let me know if this helps or if you need more clarification. Otherwise check out a tutorial on modulo operator (%) if you aren't already familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding upon the suggestion to use modulo, you can use it as follows to wrap around easily without loops:

```
// Assuming move is called for each time frame
// We can update the location of ship using modulo when it exceeds the bounds
public void move(Dimension bounds) {
   // TODO Move the ship its speed. The ship should wrap around
   // within its box. (Hint: move the ship by the size of the
   // bounding area to wrap it around; you may need to do this
   // more than once if the ship is moving fast enough.)

   location = speed.move(location);

   if (location.getX() > bounds.width) {
      location.setLocation(location.getX() % bounds.width), location.getY());
   }
   else if (location.getX() < 0) {
      location.setLocation(bounds.width - location.getX(), location.getY());
   }

   if (location.getY() > bounds.height) {
      location.setLocation(location.getX(), location.getY() % bounds.height);
   }
   else if (location.getY() < 0) {
      location.setLocation(location.getX(), bounds.height - location.getY());
   }
}
```

You've provided a lot of code so I may have missed why you need to do this, but rather than create a new delta Vector to move the location, you can alternatively just determine the new wrapped position that the ship should be at set it per `setLocation` method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I had in mind.  I don't remember how Java handles modulus math with negative values, but depending on that, you might not even need the conditional checks.  +1

Comment: @BlackVegtable interesting suggestion, from what I've gathered, if x % y = z, then -x % y = -z. The sign for y has no impact on the result.

Comment: @BlackVegetable the code could be arguably simplified but would still need some condition testing i.e. ternary operator since negative coordinates would need to added to appropriate bound axis to correctly wrap. Whether that is more understandable I'm not so sure, but I like your suggested idea.